# Run method after binding

Tags: c#, binding, devexpress

I add a chekEdit (same as checkbox) column to devexpress extragrid (use editor repository), bind this the chekEdit to some property (string type) in datasourse. And when I click the chekEdit in EditValueChanged event I see what my binded object not to changed! But when I click another checkEdit I see what my previous object already changed, so it was changed after EditValueChanged event. But I need to run some methods after changed value in binded object. Haw can I do this?

P.S. How I know it's happen because changed in binded object to do after lose focus. But I need to run a method after changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the advanced binding properties and change the DataSourceUpdateMode to OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: I wrote 
"this.myGridControl.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;" 

in constructor end run my method in EditValueChaget event (chekEdit event), but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.
Did I do everything right?

Comment: That's probably because the DataSourceUpdateMode is set to OnValidation after the constructor. Do you set the databindings in code or in the properties window? Which ever, that is where you should set the DataSourceUpdateMode at.